# Help with scrollbar class

Tags: javascript, mootools

**Here is the scrollbar class in question:** http://jsfiddle.net/brandondurham/6SUyM/3/

Currently the height of the scroll handle is dynamic and determined by the amount of content, much like a standard browser scrollbar. I need to be able to make this static (200px), regardless of the amount of content. You can see in the code where I tried to set the height, but when I did that the handle would land in strange places when dragging.

Suggestions for making that height static instead of dynamic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being the answer:

```
this.vScrollRatio = this.vContentScrollSize / (this.vTrackSize - this.vThumbSize) - this.vContentRatio * (this.vContentScrollSize / (this.vTrackSize - this.vThumbSize));
```

Answer (score 0):

In the *update* "section"/function:

```
this.vThumbSize = (this.vTrackSize * this.vContentRatio).limit(12, this.vTrackSize);
this.vThumb.setStyle('height', 200);

this.vScrollRatio = this.vContentScrollSize / this.vTrackSize+this.vThumbSize;
```

This will set the scroll to 200px

Comment: Did you try that? It actually doesn't work. It sets the height but then the scroll math is off.

Comment: I edited the question, now it *should* be closer to what you want